# Is a value assigned to an untyped block of memory always positioned at the start of the block of memory?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand the example in Chapter 2 of the online book, [Object-Oriented Programming with ANSI-C](https://planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf). I think that I understand it, except for one thing: assigning a value to a block of memory that hasn't been type-cast. Let me explain:

There is a `struct` with two members:

```
struct String {
    const void * class;
    char * text;
};
```

The first member is to point to a `struct Class`:

```
struct Class {
    size_t size;
    // Put functions appropriate to the class in here (not shown for simplicity)
};
```

The `_String` variable is created of type `struct Class` and is initialized:

```
struct Class _String = { sizeof(struct String) };
```

The `String` variable points to `_String`:

```
const struct Class * String = & _String;
```

A block of memory is created with the size of `struct String` and `p` is set to point to that block

```
void * p = calloc(1, String->size);
```

Here's where things get wild. I guess what is happening in the following statement is the first part of the block of memory that `p` points to is assigned a pointer to the class object:

```
* (const struct Class **) p = String;
```

Is my guess correct? If so, that is wicked cool. `p` just points to a block of memory, which hasn't been cast to any type. The statement says, "Hey block of memory, here's a pointer, please insert the pointer into the block, at the start of the block".

Is it the case that when a block of memory (an uncast block of memory) is assigned a value, the value is always placed at the start of the block of memory?

To clarify my question: The block of memory that `p` points to is big (the block of memory is the size of `struct String`), so the block can hold more than a pointer. Hence my question: why does the pointer get placed at the start of the block and not the end? Is it always the case that a value will be placed at the start of a block of untyped memory?

Comment: It says cast this to a pointer to a pointer to a `Class`, dereference that, and assign the value of `String` to that pointer to a `Class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`* (const struct Class **) p = String;` is not simply an instruction to “insert a pointer into the block”. After the cast `(const struct Class **)` converts the value of `p` to a pointer to a `const struct Class *`, the `*` operator says “Make this converted pointer into an lvalue for an object at that address.”

Thus, `* (const struct Class **) p` is a reference to a `const struct Class *` at that address. It is as if you had defined an object with `const struct Class *x;` and then used the name `x` in source code like `x = String;`: The `x` is a reference to the object, and `x = String;` sets the value of that object. Similarly, `* (const struct Class **) p` is a reference to an unnamed object at `p`, and `* (const struct Class **) p = String;` sets the value of that object.

It is at the beginning of the allocated memory because that is where `p` points.

Upon reviewing the C standard, it does not explicitly say that converting the `void *` returned from `malloc` to another type, such as `const struct Class **`, produces a pointer to an object starting at the same place as the memory allocated by `malloc`. However, this is understood. Whenever we convert a `foo *` to `bar *`, if the conversion is defined and produces a pointer usable for accessing an object (obeys the relevant alignment and aliasing rules), then the `bar` object starts in the same place as the `foo` object, or, in the case of `void *`, the same starting place that the `void *` points to.

For one particular case, when a pointer to converted to a pointer to character type, the C standard says the result is a pointer to the first byte of the object. So we know that converting `malloc`’s return value to `char *` would yield a pointer to the start of the space. I do not see that the standard says this explicitly for other types, but it is understood to be the intent.

So `* (const struct Class **) p = String;` puts the value of `String` at the start of memory pointed to by `p`.

Comment: Thank you @Eric Postpischil, that is good information. But it doesn't quite answer my question, I think. The block of memory that p points to is big (the block of memory is the size of struct String), so the block can hold more than a pointer. Hence my question: why does the pointer get placed at the start of the block and not the end? Is it always the case that a value will be placed at the start of a block of untyped memory? That's really my question.

Comment: @RogerCostello How would you obtain the size of a block, it is stored in the block, but at the end? You just have the address of the start... See, you will store the size at the start instead. This way other functions can work with a variety of objects of different sizes. -- Even if not the size but the pointer to a structure containing the size is stored, the principles holds true. -- BTW, if you have changed the focus of your question, you might like to edit it and add that. Down here only a few people will find it.

Comment: Thanks @busybee I will add a clarification to my question. Apparently I wasn't too clear.

Comment: Thanks @Eric Postpischil that answers my question.